# General advice for malloc size

Tags: c

I was wondering what would be some general guidelines on how to do `malloc`. Here would be an example of two different approaches using the following function:

```
split_strings_on_separator(char ** string_array_buffer, char *string, char *separator);
// for example: split_strings_on_separator(buffer, "big,word", ",");
// ==> ["big", "word", NULL];
```

One way I could do this is to `malloc` a "big enough" chunk of memory hoping that it probably won't make a big difference as long as I have enough, so I could do something like:

```
buffer = malloc(1000);
```

The other way would be more precise and would require me to calculate the exact size of the buffer. For example something like:

```
// separator and size
char * separator = ",";
size_t len_split_on = strlen(split_on);

// string and size
char * string = "big,word";
size_t len_string = strlen(string);

// exact_buffer_size = [sizeof pointer] x [num separator occurrences + 1 (array element exists after the last (or none) separator) + 1 (NULL at end)
malloc(exact_buffer_size);
```

Is one way wrong and the other correct, or when should one approach be used over the other? Using the first approach is obviously much easier and seems to be preferable on trivially-sized memory chunks (though maybe that's a lazy/naive way of thinking about it).

Comment: The problems with #1 are (1) it wastes memory and (2) how do you know how much 'big enough' is?

Comment: @user207421 -- honestly, I don't. I've just seen some examples in a function like `readlines` when reading a book/examples where they'll just fix something like `256` or some random `MAXLINE` value. Something like this, for example: http://faculty.salina.k-state.edu/tim/CMST302/study_guide/topic5/readline.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this, because it's very broad and also very opinion based.

Comment: The 2 approaches are: 1. do an initial pass to count "big enough", and 2. use `realloc` to double the size as you go.

Comment: Your university code explicitly defends against the buffer being too small, in several ways. What you posted merely 'hopes'.

Comment: General advice - start with a reasonable number of pointers for anticipated data. If you have no idea, start with `2` and then `realloc` doubling the number each time `realloc` is needed. That is probably answered at least 20-times over on questions concerning `mailloc` and dynamic memory allocation.